# Where does azuredevops server 2019 repositories are stored physically in server

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

Curious to know where does azuredevops server 2019 store repositories physically in server.

Comment: It doesn't. Repos are stored in the Azure DevOps database.

Comment: Hi there, not get your latest news. Please check whether my answer below can help you and feel free to comment~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, **repositories are not stored in the file system, but in the Azure DevOps Server database.**

You can search the database for `%git%` or `%tfvc%` to find all the information about the repository.

One advantage of storing all your data in a database is that it simplifies data management because you don’t have to back up individual client computers. In other words, you can back up your data more easily.

Your Git repository is safe as long as you have properly configured the server backup of your Azure DevOps server.